# dynamically design asp.net webpage which can configured by admin users

Tags: asp.net

I want to design an asp.net webpage at run-time which are configured by admin user.

Means , Admin user will define metadata of a webpage (they will define the number and type of controls user will see based on different condition).

Once the page definitions are defined by admin users the normal users will see different view of a page based on their role.

Please suggest which is the best way to address this requirement. I am using Asp.net 2010.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is fairly broad, open-ended question which is not good for this forum IMO.  Do you have any ideas yourself of how to accomplish this?  Without knowing more, it sounds like you want a CMS.

Comment: have you tried to use webparts?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of information to go on here.  Do all users see the same page?  Are there groups of users who see different items?  Or are the pages fully customized for each user?

I would make a database of users and fields.  For example, fields could be "CanAccessFoo" and "CanAccessBar", etc.  Admins would have a page where they can edit users to change these.  You could implement a group as well such as "View Only" that has certain properties and assign users to that group.

Then in your page (you don't even say if you're using MVC or web pages), you would dynamically show the controls based on your model which must contain the user.

```
@if (Model.User.CanAccessFoo) {
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foo)
}
```